# Is Matlab Mobile Now Useless?

Tags: matlab, sensors

Does Matlab Mobile still connect to the Desktop version?

Matlab Mobile for iOS previously connected to Matlab desktop on the LAN.

But now it only connect MathWorks Cloud? (!)
(Even if not connected, it will automatically connect with the saved credentials.)

The MathWorks documentation indicates in step (7) that it will always modify the Desktop environment:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlabmobile/ug/stream-sensor-data-with-sensor-controls.html

But that does not happen. `m = mobiledev` on the mobile device correctly creates `m` on the iPad, but does not set `m` in the Matlab Desktop environment.

Surely MathWorks wouldn't completely gut their app. There must still be a way to get sensor data in real time from multiple mobile devices streaming back to Matlab desktop?

Comment: Does anyone use Matlab Mobile for sensor data collection?